# Data validation on Microservices HTTP GET call

Tags: rest, security, asp.net-web-api, webapi

General question on Web API REST calls. In the following scenario:

**Service A** CALLS **Service B** CALLS **External third-party Service**.

Service B calls out to an external third party with an **HTTP GET**, uses the data in a compare and returns the data to the consuming Service A. The data is not modified in Service B before returning to A.

Service A would store the data to a system of record.

QUESTION: Where do you validate the data coming back from the external third party? If this is done in Service B, there would be a very high likelihood of false positives. Should both API's perform validation? Only B where it's stored or modified in a PUT/POST call to guard against SQL injection or JavaScript returned in the fields?